# setRootPath() in QT FIleSystemModel to a file

Tags: qt

I'm building a simple file browser using QT, and I can't seem to get the setRootPath() of my model to be set to a file, rather than just a directory.

Ex:

```
setRootPath("/Users/Foo/Bar") works, but

setRootPath("/Users/Foo/Bar/readme.txt") simply sets the root path to "."
```

Not sure what I'm missing.  Everything else within my application works fine.

Comment: setRootPath() works on directories, not files. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I realized I was needlessly changing the root path within my application when I could just change the root index within a given view.  So now everything is sorted out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
QFileInfo m_FileInfo = QString("C:/Users/Foo/Bar/readme.txt");
setRootPath(m_FileInfo.absolutePath());
```

What we're doing is using QFileInfo to get the [absolutePath()](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qfileinfo.html#absolutePath) of the file. So it'll set the root path to C:/Users/Foo/Bar.